# Does Plesk hold statistics about cms used?

Tags: dns, content-management-system, plesk

I have a server which hosts numerous domains.  Does Plesk have some kind of statistics that allows me to see what each domain has in them in respect to CMS and the like or do I have to go through each individual domain to find this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Plesk, it is not possible to know which CMS is installed on your client account.
You need to iterate each of your domains and see the installments.

Answer (score 0):

If you talking about applications installed on domain from APS catalog, so there is page in Plesk 11 in server settings: Server > Applications & Databases > Application Vault.
Obviously, there is no statistics for custom applications installed by user manually.

But why you need such information? What is the final goal?